# Getting ORA-00937 although selected column is included in the GROUP By clause

Tags: oracle, group-by

Below is my SQL. I don't know what else to do to not receive "not a single-group group function" error.

```
SELECT PP.PENSIONERID,SUM(ROUND(EXP(SUM(LN(INFIDX)))*AMOUNT,2))AMOUNT
FROM AG_PEN_PARTS PP
JOIN LAG_INF_INDICES INF ON INF.INFYEAR>=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PP.BEGDATE)
GROUP BY PP.PENSIONERID,PP.AMOUNT
```

I can't include ROUND(EXP(SUM(LN(INFIDX)))*AMOUNT,2) in the GROUP BY clause as group functions are not allowed there. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here're my two tables:

```
LAG_INF_INDICES:  INFYEAR | INFIDX
                  ----------------
                    2010     1.079
                    2011     1.116
                    2012     1.011
                    2013     1.024

 AG_PEN_PARTS:      PENSIONERID | BEGDATE   | AMOUNT
                    ------------------------------
                        112      07/20/2013   120
                        113      01/10/2012   100
                        112      12/12/2010   90
                        114      03/05/2011   70
```

here's the result I would expect to get:

```
      PENSIONERID  |  AMOUNT
      ----------------------
            112      235.08
            113      103.53
            114      80.87
```

So for instance, for the pensionerid 112 there're two records. First I need to multiply 90 with the multiplication of the INFIDX values beginning from 2010 and then 120 with the multiplication of the INFIDX values beginning from 2013 and then get sum of these two values.

Comment: Can you please try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499796/product-aggregate-function)

Comment: @mikejm you can also write your own product() aggregate function!

Comment: @MikeJM I completely rewrote my answer - for your example input, it now returns the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working, move the second SUM to another SELECT with a second GROUP BY:

```
SELECT PENSIONERID, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT FROM (
  SELECT PP.PENSIONERID, ROUND(EXP(SUM(LN(INFIDX)))*AMOUNT,2) AMOUNT
  FROM AG_PEN_PARTS PP
  JOIN LAG_INF_INDICES INF ON INF.INFYEAR>=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PP.BEGDATE)
  GROUP BY PP.PENSIONERID, AMOUNT
) GROUP BY PENSIONERID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22523/1)

Comment: You removed SUM from EXP(SUM(LN(INFIDX))). But this is very crucial for me as this way I am able to get the multiplication of the column values. You know, this is kind of a hack to achieve what Oracle does not provide out of the box. My expected result is the PENSIONERID and AMOUNT multiplied by the multiplication of the INFIDX columns in the LAG_INF_INDICES table.

Comment: Please add sample input and output - for me, it's hard to understand how exactly this summation is supposed to work. Are you trying to compute the product of the column values by using a combination of LN, EXP and SUM?

Comment: Please take a look at the question, I've added the input  expected result

Comment: Completely rewrote the answer.

Comment: Yes, it really worked. I don't know why I couldn't think of this earlier. Thanks a lot