# My own GROUP BY function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to be able to create my own GROUP BY function. Like one has AVG() or SUM() functions which can be used in GROUP BY where average and sum is calculated from values in each particular group, I'd like to be able to create my own function which will calculate something from values in group. Let's say I'd like to create MYFN() function which will calculate Σx^2/n (x is value in group and n number of values in group). The usage of this function should look like this:

```
SELECT mygroup,MYFN(x)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mygroup
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

How to do that?

Comment: Can you please post a small smple data and desired result, say using the function you described. It's not that clear to me how to evaluate such a function in a group of values

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499796/product-aggregate-function) has some information on Oracle's methods for custom group functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mygroup, sum(ColFun) As ColFun FROM
(
  SELECT mygroup,MYFN(x) As ColFun FROM mytable
)Y
GROUP BY mygroup
```

Comment: Why is the function SUM used here?

Comment: @sbrbot  want function Like  AVG() or SUM()  ....