# Row data multiplication in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Consider following table where I am doing row data multiplication:

```
with v1 (member_id, the_number) as 
(
select 1, 3 from dual union all
select 1, 5 from dual union all
select 2, 2 from dual union all
select 2, 3 from dual union all
select 2, 4 from dual union all
select 3, 9 from dual union all
select 3, 3 from dual union all
select 3, 2 from dual
)
select member_id, EXP(SUM(LN(the_number))) from v1
GROUP BY member_id;
```

It gives the correct result as:

```
MEMBER_ID   EXP(SUM(LN(THE_NUMBER)))
1           15
2           24
3           54
```

The moment I put a negative value in the `the_number` column, I get the following Oracle error: `ORA-01428: argument 'x' is out of range` This is because the range for `LN ()` argument is > 0.

How can I modify the query so that I can have negative values as well in `the_number` column? I am using `Oracle 11g`.

Comment: You can't use negative numbers. [LN function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions082.htm#SQLRF00659) calculates the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) which, by definition, can be defined for any positive real number. For negative numbers it is undefined - cannot be calculated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product() aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499796/product-aggregate-function)

Comment: @krokodilko : I already mentioned that range for LN () argument is > 0 in my question. I know that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the product of the absolute values of the numbers and finally multiply by `-1` or `1` depending on whether there is an odd or even number of **negative** numbers:

```
select 
  member_id,
  CASE WHEN MOD(SUM(CASE WHEN the_number < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 2) = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END *
  EXP(SUM(LN(ABS(the_number)))) from v1
GROUP BY member_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dcf876c34687cfc5dd5908cd96a99dc).