# Need help in Understanding the below Calculation in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

I need to understand the below logic. I want to implement the same in SQL so.

```
=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1
```

K34, K35, K36 are decimal numbers
Ex:

```
0.010650756,
0.010277736,
0.009844609
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: [Google what `PRODUCT` does](https://www.google.com/search?q=PRODUCT+Excel), then make your own attempt(s). If you get stuck, then show us what you've tried, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what the point of is for 1+ and -1.

Comment: It's for Oracle, but the solution for SQL server is identical (apart from that Oracle's `ln` function is `LOG` in SQL Server): [Product() aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499796/product-aggregate-function). Again, a quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+product+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com) is your friend.

Comment: i am clear on what product does. but  not sure about 1 + (K34:K36)

Comment: since its a decimal number adding 1 and substracting 1 later

Comment: *"but not sure about 1 + (K34:K36)"* That has nothing to do with SQL Server, and more your lack of understand of Excel Expressions. `K34:K36` means the cells "between" cells `K34` and `K36` inclusive; so `K34`, `K35` and `K36`. if you had `K34:L35` the it would bee `K34`, `L34`, `K35` and `L35`.

Comment: Though the `1+` at the start is odd, that basically breaks the range and means that only the first value will be returned, and then 1 added to it. So `1+(K34:K36)` will return `K34 + 1`. So in actuality `=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1` would be the same as `=K34`...

Comment: The formula isn't actually `{=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1}` is it? (Note the braces.) if so, this is *not* the same as `=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1`

Comment: The result of =(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1 where K34=0.010650756, 
K35=0.010277736, K36=0.009844609 is 0.031089677

Where as Product(K34:K36) is 
1.07765E-06

Comment: @Pavithra , no the result of `=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1` is `0.010650756`. TRhe results of `{=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1}` is `0.031089677`.

Comment: {=(PRODUCT(1+(K34:K36)))-1} ... Can you please explain me this?

Comment: YOu have an array formula...

Comment: excel shows an array function formula

Comment: yes, this is the piece of information we were missing, @Pavithra .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot of guess work, but I'm dumping this all in the comments.

Firstly, as I've described in the comments, the formula you have posted doesn't make sense. Let's *assume* you have the data as below (I have included the formula where relevant):

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | `=(PRODUCT(1+(B1:B3)))-1` | 0.010650756 |
| **2** |  | 0.010277736 |
| **3** |  | 0.009844609 |

The value returned for A1 here is `0.010650756`. This is because, effectively, `1+(B1:B3)` will return the value of the first cell + 1; in this case `1 + 0.010650756`. The `PRODUCT` of a single value is the value, and then you subtract the `1`, which gives you the original number.

What I suspect you actually have is `{=(PRODUCT(1+(B1:B3)))-1}`. Notice that the function is wrapped in braces (`{}`). This signifies an Array formula and these work differently. In this case `1+(B1:B3)` would not return `1.010650756` but instead would add `1` to *each* value as it's aggregated.

So, for the above, `=PRODUCT(B1:B3)` would be `0.010650756 * 0.010277736 * 0.009844609`, *however* `{=PRODUCT(1+(B1:B3))}` would be `1.010650756 * 1.010277736 * 1.009844609`.

As I noted in the comment, there is no native function for `PRODUCT` in T-SQL, however, I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499796/product-aggregate-function) for Oracle, that can easily be adopted for SQL Server. So using the same data:

```sql
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(1+V.D)))-1 AS Product
FROM (VALUES(0.010650756),(0.010277736),(0.009844609))V(D);
```

Which gives `0.0310896771256735`.