# Can Oracle's user-defined aggregation function be defined for use with two columns?

Tags: oracle

I'd like to implement a custom regression aggregate function, that is similar to the existing `REGR_SLOPE`.

The function I want to define needs to get two columns as a parameter, e.g.

```
select 
   T.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   CUSTOM_REGR_SLOPE(T.DATE, T.SALARY) as SALARY_TREND
from (...) T
group by T.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

The Oracle's documentation suggests it may not be possible, but I may be bad at reading between the lines ;-) .

We use Oracle 12.

Comment: You're asking if it's possible to define a function that accepts two parameters that can be called from SQL?

Comment: @Boneist The custom aggregate function, which technically speaking is a custom type; yes.

Comment: Did you try? You can call functions with as many in parameters as you like from SQL (so long as the function satisfies the conditions that allow it to be called from SQL, of course!).

Comment: Heres an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001583/need-to-find-average-processing-time-between-all-timestamp-records-in-oracle-sql/21003402#21003402) of creating a custom aggregation function for intervals, you can use as a template for yours

Comment: @tbone The function in the example takes only ONE argument - the date to be integrated. I need to make an analytic function that gets TWO columns as an input.

Comment: @Boneist I don't know how to start - I guess what I'd need is a different declaration of `ODCIAggregateIterate` mandatory member, so it can get two values instead of one. Or maybe there is a different technique?

Comment: A quick google throws up [this from Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:250238800346872505), where he defines a record that you can pass in as the single allowed parameter ... and the record can have multiple fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, its possible if you really want/need to.  You can do something like this:

First, create an object type:

```
create or replace type two_nums_t as object
(
num1 number,
num2 number
);
```

Then create your custom spec:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TotalSumPair
AS OBJECT (
runningSum1 number,
runningCnt1 number,
runningSum2 number,
runningCnt2 number,

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( actx IN OUT TotalSumPair
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  IN OUT TotalSumPair,
    val   IN     two_nums_t
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self             IN   TotalSumPair,
    returnValue  OUT  NUMBER, -- return 
    flags           IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge
  (self  IN OUT TotalSumPair,
   ctx2 IN      TotalSumPair
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
```

And custom body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TotalSumPair AS
STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( actx IN OUT TotalSumPair
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  BEGIN
    IF actx IS NULL THEN
      actx := TotalSumPair(0,0,0,0);
    ELSE
      actx.runningSum1 := 0;
      actx.runningCnt1 := 0;
      actx.runningSum2 := 0;
      actx.runningCnt2 := 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  IN OUT TotalSumPair,
    val   IN     two_nums_t
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.runningSum1 := self.runningSum1 + nvl(val.num1,0);
    self.runningSum2 := self.runningSum2 + nvl(val.num2,0);
    self.runningCnt1 := self.runningCnt1 + 1;
    self.runningCnt2 := self.runningCnt2 + 1;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self        IN  TotalSumPair,
    ReturnValue OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN  NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    --if (runningCnt1 <> 0) then
        returnValue := (self.runningSum1 + self.runningSum2);
    --else
    --    returnValue := self.runningSum1;
    --end if;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge
  (self IN OUT TotalSumPair,
   ctx2 IN     TotalSumPair
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.runningSum1 := self.runningSum1 + ctx2.runningSum1;
    self.runningCnt1 := self.runningCnt1 + ctx2.runningCnt1;
    self.runningSum2 := self.runningSum2 + ctx2.runningSum2;
    self.runningCnt2 := self.runningCnt2 + ctx2.runningCnt2;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

END;
```

Define your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_sum_pair( x two_nums_t) 
RETURN number  PARALLEL_ENABLE
AGGREGATE USING TotalSumPair;
```

Now call it like so:

```
with x as (
 select 'X' as id, 1 as num1, 2 as num2 from dual
 union all
 select 'X' as id, 3 as num1, 4 as num2 from dual
 union all
 select 'Z' as id, 5 as num1, 6 as num2 from dual
)
select id, total_sum_pair(two_nums_t(num1, num2)) sum
from x
group by id;
```

Output:

```
ID  SUM
X   10
Z   11
```

This sums both numbers for each X rows (1+2+3+4), and each Y rows (5+6).

Phew! ;)

Comment: Tip if you add "map member function' to two_nums_t, you can call it with distinct staement.

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS1942) doesn't suggest it may not be possible, it states it:

> **Restriction on AGGREGATE USING**
>   If you specify this clause, then you can specify only one input argument for the function.

As others have noted, that one input argument can be an object type or collection etc.; but you can't define your own aggregate function that you call quite as simply as you showed, `CUSTOM_REGR_SLOPE(T.DATE, T.SALARY)`.